# System variable set on mac terminal is not available from java appllication

Tags: java, macos, operating-system, environment-variables

I add this to the bottom of ~/.bash_profile

```
TEST_VAR=testPass
export TEST_VAR
```

then on mac terminal execute `source ~/.bash_profile`

I can now print the value out using - `echo $TEST_VAR`

From my java application both `System.getProperty("TEST_VAR")` and `System.getenv("TEST_VAR")` return null.

The new variable doesn't show up when I list all env vars in the java app using

```
System.getProperties().entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result using the following code:

```
public class TestExportProp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        System.out.println(System.getenv("TEST_ENV_VAR"));
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to execute this code where you set the environment variable e.g.

```
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: export TEST_ENV_VAR=varTest
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: echo $TEST_ENV_VAR
varTest
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: javac TestExportProp.java 
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: java TestExportProp
varTest
```

If you want to read all variables, you can use the following code:

```
Map <String, String> map = System.getenv();
for (Map.Entry <String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Environment variable: " + entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

**Update:**

I can see that you have updated your question. Please note that the solution still works without any change i.e. after executing `source ~/.bash_profile`, change the directory to the location where your class is and run your class e.g.

```
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: javac TestExportProp.java 
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: java TestExportProp
testPass
```

Comment: What if I want to read from a variable from ```~/.bash_profile```

Comment: But does this mean the java application has to be deployed in the same folder as bash_profile ?

Comment: ok but this won't work when running from an IDE, I am using IntelliJ and I can't print the variable?

Comment: OK you are right that works, I am accepting the answer. I presume this is just an IDE issue then once i deploy my JAR on a server/ec2 it should work fine in retrieving the variable?